# Smooch: get the `extracted_data` returned by Motion.ai bot

Tags: smooch, supportkit

I am using Smooch with a Motion.ai chat bot. The chat bot has the ability to extract machine readable data from a user's response, e.g. telephone numbers and email addresses. This `extracted_data` is included in the payload [if you set up a webhook](http://docs.motion.ai/v1.0/docs/extracted-data) with Motion.ai. It is also included if you interact with the Motion.ai bot via it's API. Since I assume Smooch connects to motion.ai bot via the latter's API, is it possible to retrieve that `extracted_data` somehow and store it as part of the `properties` for an app user in the Smooch database. As far as I can see it is not stored in the Smooch database as part of the message object.

Answer (score 0):

Motion.ai is actually the one that calls the Smooch API. They could use the [Update appUser API](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#update-app-user) to add the `extracted_data` inside the appUser `properties`.

Alternatively, you might be able to setup a [Motion.ai webhook](http://docs.motion.ai/v1.0/docs/webhook) to receive the `replyData` and call the Smooch API given that the recipient info given by motion.ai can be mapped to a smooch appUser.